# VNC connection from windows to raspi running buster

Tags: vnc, raspbian-buster

I am trying to establish a vnc from windows to raspi buster which does not work so far.

Status is as follows:

- ssh with putty is up and running I have switched on vnc in `sudo
  raspi-config`
- I have selected display resolution 85 in `sudo raspi-config`
- I am using realvnc-vnc-server on the raspi I am using
  realvnc on windows
- When I try to connect, I can enter user and password and the connection establishes, but the final result is "desktop cannot be shown".

I have tried different alternatives and packackes, but cannot get things running. Which is annoying, because vnc worked well a year ago (using tightvnc at that time, which does not work either at the moment).

I have also tried a route using xrdp but also without success.

What would be the standard route to access a display on a raspi running buster from a windows pc?

EDIT:
If have now additionally set the boot option in sudo raspi config so that the desktop automatically starts, but requires a user login. While I still cannot log in due to missing credentials, this seems to be the correct path.

EDIT2:
Something seems strange with my vncserver process. The command `vncserver` delivers no error and shows the IP to which I should connect. However `vncserver -kill :1` does not work (XServer process cannot be terminated), and repeating the vncserver command does not count up the display numbers, but always hands back 192.168.178.49:1

EDIT3: (for buster on a Raspi 4)

> systemctl status vncserver-x11-serviced.service

(after having startet vncserver which offers an IP address to connect to) shows the following:

```
* vncserver-x11-serviced.service - VNC Server in Service Mode daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vncserver-x11-serviced.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-08-08 07:54:44 CEST; 1h 11min ago
 Main PID: 516 (vncserver-x11-s)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 1599)
   Memory: 8.2M
   CGroup: /system.slice/vncserver-x11-serviced.service
           |-516 /usr/bin/vncserver-x11-serviced -fg
           `-523 /usr/bin/vncserver-x11-core -service

Aug 08 07:54:44 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started VNC Server in Service Mode daemon.
Aug 08 07:54:45 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[523]: ServerManager: Server started
Aug 08 07:54:45 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[523]: ConsoleDisplay: Cannot find a running X server on vt1
```

EDIT4: (for strech on a Raspi 3 B+)
I have tried the same on a different Raspi under strech. The output is somewhat different, now there is an X Server running:

```
 vncserver-x11-serviced.service - VNC Server in Service Mode daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vncserver-x11-serviced.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-08-07 21:46:58 CEST; 16s ago
 Main PID: 498 (vncserver-x11-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/vncserver-x11-serviced.service
           ├─498 /usr/bin/vncserver-x11-serviced -fg
           └─510 /usr/bin/vncserver-x11-core -service

Aug 07 21:46:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started VNC Server in Service Mode daemon.
Aug 07 21:46:59 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[510]: ServerManager: Server started
Aug 07 21:46:59 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[510]: ConsoleDisplay: Cannot find a running X server on vt1
Aug 07 21:46:59 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[510]: ConsoleDisplay: Found running X server (pid=531, binary=/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg)
Aug 07 21:46:59 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[510]: AgentInitCheck: agent comms failure
Aug 07 21:47:04 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[510]: ConsoleDisplay: Cannot find a running X server on vt7
Aug 07 21:47:04 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[510]: AgentInitCheck: no response from agent
Aug 07 21:47:09 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[510]: AgentInitCheck: agent comms failure
```

EDIT5: 
I have set up a raspi 3 with a clean strech image. 
The good news: The XServer is running:

```
 vncserver-x11-serviced.service - VNC Server in Service Mode daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/vncserver-x11-serviced.service; enabl
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-08-08 13:20:23 CEST; 8s ago
 Main PID: 5067 (vncserver-x11-s)
   CGroup: /system.slice/vncserver-x11-serviced.service
           |-5067 /usr/bin/vncserver-x11-serviced -fg
           |-5068 /usr/bin/vncserver-x11-core -service
           `-5078 /usr/bin/vncagent service 15

Aug 08 13:20:23 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started VNC Server in Service Mode daemo
Aug 08 13:20:23 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[5068]: ServerManager: Server started
Aug 08 13:20:23 raspberrypi vncserver-x11[5068]: ConsoleDisplay: Found running X
~
```

The bad news: Wgen I try to connect with the realvnc viewer, I get a graphical login window, but after typing in user/password, the same window keeps popping up, no login possible.

Comment: I found realvnc to be too heavyweight for my liking. I wrote up detailed directions for using either tightvnc or tigervnc. If you're not adverse to working at the bash command line, these definitely work: https://github.com/gitbls/RPiVNCHowTo.

Comment: Does your Pi boot to the GUI?

Comment: I guess we should ask: What is your preferred solution? Connecting via VNC to your Pi console (which would be running the graphical desktop interface), or connecting to a new virtual desktop, independent of your console desktop?

Comment: @bls: I have tried tightvnc, same problem.

Comment: @Milliways: Tried it both ways: boot to GUI and boot without GUI and start vncserver manually, makes no difference. I only have headless operation, no monitor attached. When booting to GUI, I have been asked to install desktop packages and have done so.

Comment: @bls: I'll take any of those as soon as it works. I am sure that I make some pretty dump mistake here at teh moment, but I am really lost.

Comment: What does `systemctl status vncserver-x11-serviced.service` show? (edit answer into your Question)

Comment: It "Cannot find a running X server" so there is NOTHING to connect TO. (Ignore the message on vt1 - there should be a "Found running X server" displayed after this). As we don't know what you have done (wrong) it is difficult to help. It works for the rest of us following the Foundation tutorial - I suggest you try with a clean installation.

Comment: @tfv suggest that you take a look at the link that I mentioned above. It's super-simple, and works with both Full and Lite. You'll need to sudo systemctl disable vncserver-x11-serviced.service before everything will work, but it WILL work. I tested it this morning on Raspbian Full and it took me about 15 minutes start to finish. Up to you, of course!

Comment: @bls It seems that working on a Raspian full image already solved the problem, without the need of additional software.

Comment: @tfv great to hear that you got it working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem went away when I worked with a (full) buster image which included desktop functionality (but no additional software)

It seems that the lite images from buster and strech did not start the x server functionality properly, nor did the operations described in the links above.

Answer (score 0):

The Foundation tutorial [VNC (Virtual Network Computing)](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md) explains how to setup ReadVNC.

NOTE is there is no screen attached the display will be small, however you can set Default resolution in `raspi-config`

The tutorial includes instructions for **Creating a virtual desktop** for headless operation.

Comment: I have tried exactly this. I have set default resolution to 85. I have created a virtual desktop. I am using RealVNC VNC viewer, latest version. I have started vnc server and it shows the IP to which I should connect. However, when I try to connect to the virtual desktop created (192.168.178.49:1), I get a timeout, and when I try to connect to 192.168.178.49, I get a "desktop cannot be displayed". I have tried to switch on boot to display in raspi-config, makes no difference.

Comment: Something seems strange with my vncserver process. The command `vncserver` delivers no error and shows the IP to which I should connect. However `vncserver -kill :1` does not work (XServer process cannot be terminated), and repeating the vncserver command does not count up the display numbers, but always hands back 192.168.178.49:1 .